# How to identify the element currently visible on the screen. I am using "scroll-snap-type"

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, scroll-snap-type

thank you for reading!

I'm currently using the 'scroll-snap-type' to implement something like a YouTube short.
It's like swiping to switch to the next content.

At that time, I want to detect the content currently displayed on the screen.
How can I do that?

thank you.

Comment: element.getClientRects()[0] (mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) will have coordinates on the screen if your element is on the screen.

Comment: If your question is not how to check a specific element for whether it is in the viewport, but to dynamically determine which element(s) currently is/are - then your keyword is [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: thank you! I was able to solve it with "Intersection Observer API"!